# WiFi isn't working 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, rfkill

On my 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 WiFi isn't working - my WiFi networks are not visible to choose from. I got the following result:

```
$ lspci -vq | grep -i wireless -B 1 -A 5

01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fea00000 (32-bit,ran the following command  non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Is this a case of a missing driver? My Ethernet connection works fine.

Edit:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

It still does not see the WiFi networks.

Ubuntu Paste link deleted.

Ubuntu Paste link deleted.

```
"$ sudo iwlist scan
[sudo] password for <myname>: 
wlp1s0    No scan results

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

tun0      Interface doesn't support scanning."
```

Rebooting. This is a desktop system, not a laptop. It sits about five feet from the router.

Disconnected the internet, rebooted, ran the command, and reconnected the internet.
dmesg | grep -e rt2 -e wlp > info.txt

```
[   13.959601] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3090, rev 3213 detected
[   13.970464] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0005 detected
[   14.091851] rt2800pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   20.466123] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Editing is complete as you requested.

Comment: You have a driver, the wireless is not disabled by the Airplane Mode switch and so it seems that you have a bigger issue. Please provide the wireless info from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Posted as requested.

Comment: What is the tun0 interface about? Is this a virtual machine or some such?

Comment: I don't know what tun0 is. I don't know if it's a virtual machine, but I didn't set it up to be one. I do have a VPN (IVPN) set up but that shouldn't stop me from seeing the network SSIDs. IVPN does run something like a virtual DNS to prevent leakage and that has a private IP address space: 10.xx.yy.1. IVPN: "When a vpn connection is established, we push a DNS server to your system that is safe and leak-proof." Maybe that has something to do with it; works fine on my Mac. As far as this Linux setup goes, the machine is a vanilla Gateway SX-2370 and I did a standard Ubuntu install.

Comment: May I see: `dmesg | grep -e rt2 -e wlp` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result and give me the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Results were short and are now pasted.

Comment: Is this a laptop? Are there scan results if you stand next to the router? `sudo iwlist scan` Please detach the ethernet, reboot and run: `dmesg | grep -e rt2 -e wlp > info.txt` Insert the ethernet and find and paste info.txt. Frankly, I see no reason at all that it isn't working.

Comment: You can use a usb wireless wifi adapter.

Comment: Pasted into the original question.

Comment: I still see nothing wrong and therefore fixable. Is there an antenna connection on the wireless card? Are you quite sure it is securely snapped or screwed in place?

Comment: The only thing I'm certain of is that neither the original owner nor I have had the cover off of the box; it's possible it was dead from Gateway. I don't recall whether the original owner (now departed) used Ethernet or WiFi. I really appreciate your effort and there's really no trouble for me to leave it where it is and remain Ethernet-connected. Thank you, and if I buy a new card and it works I'll post it here. Again, thanks.

Comment: Thank you, and I may well try this in the future, but right now I think I'll leave it wired.